# Wiring to install new pendant light

Tags: electrical

[image][image]Trying to install a new pendant light but 1 of the outlet has 2 white, 2 black and 2 ground wires in it. How do i connect those with the new light fixture wiring?

Comment: The same way the old, working fixture was connected to them.

Comment: Black to black, white to white, ground to ground.   Without more details from you, there is no way to give more details about what to do.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the associated switch box please?

Comment: @RMDman  If it was wired up as an old style switch loop, that might not work.

Comment: @ crip659, that's my point. We don't know anything about how this was done.

Comment: @RMDman  The OP might not catch that point, and just do it that way.

Comment: Maybe and maybe not.  it may work and it may not.  Point is we DON'T know enough about the situation to say something may not work.  My point was to get more info from the OP.

Comment: Bulb sockets to the 2nd outlet was attached in such a way as shown in the picture: 2 white to nickel screws, 2 black to brass screws and 2 copper were capped together.

Comment: We have 2 outlet for pendant lights which had bulb sockets installed and now we want to install pendant lights. 1st outlet has 1 black, 1 white and 1 copper wire which is good and attached image is of 2nd outlet where we have 6 wires.

Comment: @user176237 you keep calling them outlets - but there should be no outlets. Do you mean the fixtures (i.e. the holes in the ceiling where you stick the lights), or do you mean the light switch itself? Is there one hole controlled by 2 switches at 2 different parts of the room (a 3-pole configuration), or is there two holes controlled by 1 switch? I am guessing you are not asking to turn this hardwired light fixture into something you plug into the wall, given there is already wire supplying this fixture.

Comment: Yes, I meant the black box which is in the picture where the wires are pulled from.  There is 1 switch for 2 pendant lights. Initially there were bulbs which is in the picture attached white cap. We are replacing it with the new pendant lights which has 3 wires and black box has 6 wires.

Answer (score 0):

1. Those ground wires are not right. They need to be joined with an appropriately sized ground wire nut.

[image]

2. It looks like this light fixture is wired in series with one or more other lights. So one black and neutral wire pair is the feed from the light switch, the switch leg, that is controlled by the light switch and powers that fixture. The other pair loads the other light fixtures. Those actually may be dead and nutted off in a junction box - hopefully not with electrical tape.
3. You don't technically need to know which cable is which, the new fixture should go in by connecting all the black wires, connecting all the neutral wires, and connecting all the ground wires. In addition, one of the ground wires should be attached to the pendant itself if the pendant is metal, preventing the fixture from ever becoming electrified in case of a short. The white mounting plate in your picture shows three screw holes through which the fixture wire is meant to be fed and screwed down. Gold for hot, silver for neutrals, and there seems to be a missing ground screw which is colored green. You may already have a ground screw for this - it's green, or else you need to buy a ground screw.
4. If the load cable is not feeding any current fixture, and you're not wiring it to an active fixture, you can nut it off in the black receptacle and tuck it off to the side. In that case you DO need to know which cable is the switch leg, to do so, separate the wires, turn the power on, set your voltimeter to the correct value, and try to complete the circuit with the leads. If you read 120V across the black and neutral wires from the same cable, then that's the switchleg and the other cable can be deprecated.

Comment: Probably, "in series" means "in parallel"

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg you don't send up two switch legs from the switch though.

Comment: Why do you need to ground a plastic box and a plastic fixture?

Comment: @Huesmann I thought plastic was the old and op didn't picture the new. Judging from the cut wires...